# how to optimize the aggregation query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Now I'm using ES to do aggregation. The basic logic can be expressed as

```
select count(*)
from 
(select key, count(*) from table where ***
```

group by key having count(*) > c 
) z 
and here the where filter condition is specified by end-user,which means I cannot do any pre-work.
And I've implemented the logic using bucket selector .

However in my case, there are usually several millions of distinct keys, which means there are several millions of buckets returned by ES, sorted by their doc_count by default. And this is very time consuming. I don't know if there are some strategies which can speedup the query, for example turn off the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your query does do the following:

1. Group all entries by `key`
2. Remove all grouped entries where `count <= c`
3. Count all remaining grouped entries

Then the `SELECT key, count(*)` is useless, because it's never getting used again. You can simply use `SELECT 1`.

Sorting isn't needed at all for this query.

---

There are basically 3 ways to speed up this query:

1. Get more servers! This aggregation can be easily executed in parallel by ES on multiple nodes.
2. Don't aggregate the data when needed, but use a background task, that executes once a day. This background task will basically create the same data as you can see below in `STORE 2`. Of course this way you will always have to deliver old data, but it will speed up things!
3. Preaggregate your data! Use some simple Key-Value Storage (or maybe even just stick with ES for this operation), and then do the following:

   - When a new document is getting inserted: Get its key, and increment the number.
   - When a document is getting deleted: Get its key, and decrement the counter.

Then you basically have 2 stores: 1 for the actual documents, and 1 for the aggregated data, i.e.

```
STORE 1:
[
  {id: 1, key: foo, ...},
  {id: 2, key: foo, ...},
  {id: 3, key: bar, ...},
  {id: 4, key: baz, ...}
]

STORE 2:
[
  {id: foo, counter: 2},
  {id: bar, counter: 1},
  {id: baz, counter: 1}
]
```

This way you do the aggregation while inserting/deleting the documents from `STORE 1`. This is of course more time consuming while inserting/deleting, because you have to touch 2 data stores every time.

But now you can simple count the entries from `STORE 2` to get your result. This will give a huge boost in query performance for this operation.

---

You see: It's always a tradeoff. You've got to decide what you need:

1. Live data + high insert / delete performance + slow aggregation
2. Not-Live data + high insert / delete performance + fast aggregation
3. Live data + slow insert / delete + fast aggregation

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I forgot to mention that the user will always add some filter conditions in their query. So before the aggregation ,I will have to do some filter work, which will make the pre-aggregation not useful. Still a lot of thanks